# Scala `.sum` performance when doing a roundtrip

Tags: scala, performance

I have a very simple code

```
  val things: Seq[Long] = (1L to 100000000L)
  val start: Long = System.nanoTime()
  val result = things.sum
  val end: Long = System.nanoTime()
  println(end-start)
```

which prints something like `1790900`, about 2ms.

However when I introduce my case class

```
case class Thing(foo: Long) extends AnyVal
```

it seems this changes everything. You don't believe me? Just watch.
I will map my sequence of longs to `Thing`s and back to a sequence of longs:

```
  val things: Seq[Long] = (1L to 100000000L).map(i => Thing(i)).map(t => t.foo)
  val start: Long = System.nanoTime()
  val result = things.sum
  val end: Long = System.nanoTime()
  println(end-start)
```

Now the benchmark is in the order of `1058361600`.

How is this possible?

When

Comment: I'd guess that the `map` is lazy, and that the runtime type of `things` is a very different one.

Comment: ok I didn't notice the `NumericRangeInclusive` was a `Seq`

Comment: @Bergi: Even more relevant, `Range` has an [overridden version of `sum`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L394), which simply computes `(size * (head + last)) / 2` in O(1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you won't get sensible timing information on the first run, you need to run it a few times for the JIT compiler to optimise the code.

But the problem here is that the `Range` is *lazy*, and `(1L to 100000000L)` simply records the start and end values, it does not allocate a vector with 100000000 elements. So when you call `sum`, the `Range` just <strike>delivers each number in turn to be added together</strike> computes the value directly **.

The second version does create a huge list of `Long` values and then adds them up, which is going to be much, much slower.

---

** Thanks to Jörg Mittag for the hint that `Range` has an overloaded implementation of `sum`.

Comment: I'm surprised that `Range` doesn't override `sum`, considering there exists a closed-form formula with worst-case time-complexity of O(1) for the sum of a range.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It turns out that it does! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate Tim's point here is jmh benchmark of

```
case class Thing(foo: Long) extends AnyVal

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So61032621 {
  val size = 100000000L
  val as = 1L to size
  val bs = (1L to size).map(i => Thing(i)).map(t => t.foo)
  @Benchmark def a: Long = as.sum
  @Benchmark def b: Long = bs.sum
}
```

where `sbt "jmh:run -i 5 -wi 5 -f 1 -t 1 -prof gc bench.So61032621"` gives

```
Benchmark                                       Mode  Cnt           Score           Error   Units
So61032621.a                                   thrpt    5    53677138.590 ±   9550110.580   ops/s
So61032621.a:·gc.alloc.rate                    thrpt    5        4679.263 ±       831.014  MB/sec
So61032621.a:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               thrpt    5          96.000 ±         0.001    B/op
So61032621.a:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space           thrpt    5        4690.565 ±       773.522  MB/sec
So61032621.a:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm      thrpt    5          96.252 ±         5.062    B/op
So61032621.a:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space       thrpt    5           0.046 ±         0.019  MB/sec
So61032621.a:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm  thrpt    5           0.001 ±         0.001    B/op
So61032621.a:·gc.count                         thrpt    5         177.000                  counts
So61032621.a:·gc.time                          thrpt    5         434.000                      ms
So61032621.b                                   thrpt    5           1.043 ±         0.039   ops/s
So61032621.b:·gc.alloc.rate                    thrpt    5        2277.815 ±        81.170  MB/sec
So61032621.b:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               thrpt    5  2399999759.273 ±         0.001    B/op
So61032621.b:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space           thrpt    5        2266.218 ±       138.781  MB/sec
So61032621.b:·gc.churn.PS_Eden_Space.norm      thrpt    5  2387779137.164 ± 117864918.226    B/op
So61032621.b:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space       thrpt    5           0.048 ±         0.028  MB/sec
So61032621.b:·gc.churn.PS_Survivor_Space.norm  thrpt    5       50641.455 ±     29244.708    B/op
So61032621.b:·gc.count                         thrpt    5         116.000                  counts
So61032621.b:·gc.time                          thrpt    5         287.000                      ms
```

Note the drastic difference in memory allocation rates

```
So61032621.a:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               thrpt    5          96.000 ±         0.001    B/op
So61032621.b:·gc.alloc.rate.norm               thrpt    5  2399999759.273 ±         0.001    B/op
```

Comment: Not only is `Range` lazy and will produce the elements one-by-one if iterated, in this specific case, it isn't iterated *at all*, since `Range` has an overloaded version of `sum` that simply uses the closed-form arithmetic solution `size * (head + last) / 2` to compute the result in O(1) with no allocations and no iteration.